# storage pulley rack for a diagonal ceiling

Tags: mountain-bike, rack, weight, storage, physics

i want a system based on a ceiling pulley for a quite heavy bike, the storage room is under the roof, so the  ceiling (cement concrete material) is not flat.

Do the ceiling racks work well?

What about the pulley and effort?
How much strenght requires to pull the rope for a 20kg bicycle?

What about the horizontal position of the bike?

Is it horizontal even if a part of the bike is heavier than the other (note1)?

(note1) rear side (battery and e-wheel)

Experiences or alternative suggestions?

[image: basic bike pulley]
[image: twice horizontal]

Comment: You'll need to say which ceiling racks you mean. Some use pulleys; of those might need to be adapted. Others just hang the bike by one wheel.

Comment: If you attach your hook / rack to the cement correctly there should be no issue hanging a bike by its wheels or it's handlebar and seat.

Comment: My main concern is not about the wheels but about the position of the bike and specifically because the pulleys at ceiling will not be at the same horizontal height

Answer (score 3):

The first, used as designed, will struggle even on a flat ceiling with a very uneven loading such as an e-bike with the battery and motor both at the rear (a mid-drive, down-tube motor design would be fine).  With an unbalanced bike Id try to get one set of hooks directly over the heavy end.  This may mean modifying the hooks to attach to a good strong rear rack. I'd also want a more positive attachment than a simple hook, at least for a heavy bike, a shackle or carabiner that couldn't possibly be knocked free. On a sloping ceiling I'd rework it to use separate front and rear ropes, but that would be harder to use.  I think there are 2-rope designs on the market but I can't quickly find them - I may be thinking of a DIY design, because I've played with such things myself. This type is available quite cheap (watch the weight limit though) and would be fairly easy to modify.

The second could sort of work.  The wall bracket would have to be positioned on a vertical wall such that the upper arm is parallel to the floor. You'd use it as designed, but the bike would end up parallel to the floor and not the ceiling, wasting space above it.

Answer (score 0):

I have one exactly like this.  When I moved house, there was nowhere with enough ceiling height to install it, and I don't miss it.

DOWNSIDES

- The hooks weren't great, and would scratch paint.  Fixed by putting some old  socks over each hook.
- The hooks sometimes didn't get a good hold on the bike, especially around the saddle.  When holding the rope, it was possible for a hook to slightly move, enough so it would still lift but not a good grasp.   Fix was to tie off the pull-rope short so I had to lift the bike a few centimetres to the hooks, once off the ground it was better
- Uneven lift - The pulleys at the pull-rope end have to move more rope, (in the ratio 1:2:2:3:4)  So any added friction in one pulley could cause the rope to move unevenly, effectively lifting one end faster than the other.  You simply held the high end back by pulling the bottom of the wheel with one hand, but that only leaves one hand on the rope so can't reposition.
- Risk - my MTB was about 12 kilos, and it fell right down once.   Scratched up the bar ends, broke a light, bent the hanger and put marks in the floor.  If someone had been underneath it would have been injurious.

UPSIDES

- These things do work, storing your bike up and out of the way and use up space in the Z axis that would otherwise be wasted.

Upshot - Nice idea, but make better hooks ideally with a positive close, something like a climber's carabiner.  You could use reusable velcro cable straps to secure bike to hooks.

---

Strength required is fairly minimal.  If you can pick up your bike, then pulling the rope requires 4 times the rope pulled through as per height it has to rise.  
 IE raising it 2 metres requires 8 metres of rope to be pulled with 1/4 the weight.  This is a "reduction gearing" common in cranes etc.

---

The two ceiling blocks don't need to be at the same height, but the last one does need to be level else the self-locking function won't work.   I'd always tie it off to a cleat and not depend on the lock anyway.

---

I would not charge the bike while its suspended in the air - that would be asking for problems if something went wrong.